# How to properly create a TSplitter on a TCustomControl Component?

Tags: delphi, components

I´m designing a new VCL component using a set of existing TControls.
The controls are placed on TPanels, some aligned to left position, one to the right position and finally one to the client area. Each of those panels has the customized component as it´s parent.

I need to place splitters between the panels, in order for the users to be able to resize the inner components.

The problem is, I simply can´t figure out the logic applied to the positioning of the splitters when created at runtime.

I visited quite a number of forums, each pointing to a different solution, but none of them worked.

Tried to:

1 - when creating the splitters, use the properties "lef"t and "width" of the component where it should be positioned aside, as its "left" property.

2 - Use the left property to assign the position where it should be.

and some others I can´t remember.

What am I missing?

In the code below, the splitters abre being created where it should be.
Just after the corresponding panel, and theirs left property corresponds to the last thing i´ve tried (it´s position).

```
constructor TDBIDBGridFilterBar.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Self.Width := 490;
  Self.Height := 23;
  Self.Constraints.MinWidth := 285;

  if fComboColunasWidth = 0 then
    fComboColunasWidth := 118;

  fBackGroundPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  fBackGroundPanel.Parent := Self;
  fBackGroundPanel.ShowCaption := false;
  fBackGroundPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  fBackGroundPanel.Align := alClient;

  fButtonsPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  fButtonsPanel.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fButtonsPanel.ShowCaption := false;
  fButtonsPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  fButtonsPanel.Width := 73;
  fButtonsPanel.Align := alLeft;

  fBtnMarcaTodos := TButton.Create(Self);
  fBtnMarcaTodos.Parent := fButtonsPanel;
  fBtnMarcaTodos.Width := 23;
  fBtnMarcaTodos.Height := 23;
  fBtnMarcaTodos.Left := 0;
  fBtnMarcaTodos.Hint := 'Marcar todos';
  fBtnMarcaTodos.ShowHint := true;

  fBtnDesmarcaTodos := TButton.Create(Self);
  fBtnDesmarcaTodos.Parent := fButtonsPanel;
  fBtnDesmarcaTodos.Width := 23;
  fBtnDesmarcaTodos.Height := 23;
  fBtnDesmarcaTodos.Left := 23;
  fBtnDesmarcaTodos.Hint := 'Desarcar todos';
  fBtnDesmarcaTodos.ShowHint := true;

  fBtnInveteSelecao := TButton.Create(Self);
  fBtnInveteSelecao.Parent := fButtonsPanel;
  fBtnInveteSelecao.Width := 23;
  fBtnInveteSelecao.Height := 23;
  fBtnInveteSelecao.Left := 46;
  fBtnInveteSelecao.Hint := 'Inverter seleção';
  fBtnInveteSelecao.ShowHint := true;

  fLabelPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  fLabelPanel.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fLabelPanel.Width := 33;
  fLabelPanel.Align := alLeft;
  fLabelPanel.ShowCaption := false;
  fLabelPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;

  fLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  fLabel.Parent := fLabelPanel;
  fLabel.Top := 4;
  fLabel.Left := 4;
  fLabel.Caption := 'Filtro:';
  fLabel.Width := 28;

  fComboColunasPan := TPanel.Create(Self);
  fComboColunasPan.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fComboColunasPan.ShowCaption := false;
  fComboColunasPan.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  fComboColunasPan.width := fComboColunasWidth;
  fComboColunasPan.Align := alLeft;

  fComboColunas := TDBIComboBox.Create(Self);
  fComboColunas.Parent := fComboColunasPan;
  fComboColunas.Text := '';
  fComboColunas.OnEnter := PopulaComboColunas;
  fComboColunas.OnChange := ComboChange;
  fComboColunas.Style := csOwnerDrawFixed;
  fComboColunas.Align := alClient;
  fComboColunas.Hint := 'Colunas';
  fComboColunas.ShowHint := true;

  fSplitterColunas := TSplitter.Create(Self);
  fSplitterColunas.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fSplitterColunas.Align := alLeft;
  fSplitterColunas.Left := 1;

  fComboOperadorPan := TPanel.Create(Self);
  fComboOperadorPan.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fComboOperadorPan.ShowCaption := false;
  fComboOperadorPan.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  fComboOperadorPan.width := fComboColunasWidth;
  fComboOperadorPan.Align := alLeft;

  fComboOperador := TDBIComboBox.Create(Self);
  fComboOperador.Parent := fComboOperadorPan;
 // fComboOperador.Items.Add(cItensComboFiltro);
  fComboOperador.Style := csOwnerDrawFixed;
  fComboOperador.Align := alClient;
  fComboOperador.Hint := 'Comparação';
  fComboOperador.ShowHint := true;
  fComboOperador.Text := '  =  ';

  fSplitterOperador := TSplitter.Create(Self);
  fSplitterOperador.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fSplitterOperador.Align := alLeft;
  fSplitterOperador.Left := 2;

  fBtnAdcFiltroPan := TPanel.Create(Self);
  fBtnAdcFiltroPan.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fBtnAdcFiltroPan.ShowCaption := false;
  fBtnAdcFiltroPan.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  fBtnAdcFiltroPan.width := 23;
  fBtnAdcFiltroPan.Align := alRight;

  fBtnAdcFiltro := TButton.Create(Self);
  fBtnAdcFiltro.Parent := fBtnAdcFiltroPan;
  fBtnAdcFiltro.Height := 23;
  fBtnAdcFiltro.Width := 23;
  fBtnAdcFiltro.Caption := '+';
  fBtnAdcFiltro.Hint := 'Adicionar filtro...';
  fBtnAdcFiltro.ShowHint := true;
  fBtnAdcFiltro.OnClick := btnNewFilterClick;

  fClientPanel := TPanel.Create(Self);
  fClientPanel.Parent := fBackGroundPanel;
  fClientPanel.ShowCaption := false;
  fClientPanel.BevelOuter := bvNone;
  fClientPanel.Align := AlClient;

  fMaskEdit := TDBIMaskEdit.Create(Self);
  fMaskEdit.Parent := fClientPanel;
  fMaskEdit.Font.Size := 9;
  fMaskEdit.Align := alTop;
end;
```

Comment: Should be `LeftSplitter.Left := ControlOnLeft.Width + 1;` presumably (without testing your code). Simply setting it to the exact width won't do the trick. However, you're in for a world of hurt with such a design. A custom control shouldn't have sub-controls in this manner. In your case, writing an embedded `TFrame` or even `TForm` would be more appropriate. It makes no sense at all for *all* of that to be in a custom control.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.I´ll try it out, but logically shouldn´t be  LeftSplitter.Left := (ControlOnLeft.left + ControlOnLeft.Width + 1) this way, I should get the correct position + 1.

Comment: It didn´t work, the damn splitter keeps getting to the left of the client aligned panel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you add the panels to the background panel in left to right order, it is sufficient to set the `Left` property of the added panels before you set the `Alignment` property, to a large enough value, so it exceeds the `Left` property of components already placed on the background panel. The value you set can even be bigger than the width of the background panel.

When you add panels or other components in a right to left order (`Alignment = alRight;`) you can leave the `Left` property as 0.

The above is true for any component you place on the background panel, also splitters. When using splitters, you probably also want to set the neighbouring components `Constraints.MinWidth` property to something like e.g. 10 to prevent the component width to accidentally be reduced to zero, and therefore become invisible. Once that happens there's no way to get it visible again with the splitter.

For example, this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := 1;
  repeat
    with TPanel.Create(self) do
    begin
      Parent := Panel1;
      Left := 510;
      Align := alLeft;
      Width := 40;
      Constraints.MinWidth := 10;
      Caption := 'L'+IntToStr(i);
    end;
    if (i = 3) or (i = 5) then
    with TSplitter.Create(self) do
    begin
      Parent := Panel1;
      Left := 510;
      Width := 10;
      Align := alLeft;
    end;
    inc(i);
  until i > 5;
  with TPanel.Create(self) do
  begin
    Parent := Panel1;
    Width := 40;
    Align := alRight;
    Caption := 'R1';
  end;
  with TPanel.Create(self) do
  begin
    Parent := Panel1;
    Width := 40;
    Align := alRight;
    Caption := 'R2';
  end;
  with TPanel.Create(self) do
  begin
    Parent := Panel1;
    Left := 510;
    Align := alClient;
    Caption := 'C';
  end;
end;
```

produces this design:

[image]

L1 .. L5 are `alLeft` aligned, C is `alClient` aligned and R1 .. R2 are `alRight` aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.
Since all the components created before are left aligned, their left property are set to 0, no matter where in the form they are located.

So, in order to fix the problem, i had to propperly fill the left property of the previous panels.

fThisPanel.left := fPreviousPanel.Left + fPreviousPanel.width + 1, and so on ...

Comment: There's no need to calculate the left property for the panels that are to be left aligned after eachother. Since you are creating them in the left to right order, just set the left property to a sufficiently large number (like 480 if the parent is the `fBackGroundPanel`) before setting the alignment.